# How to check for dirty flag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering what is the best way of checking if a page is dirty if a user chooses to navigate it from it.  For example, there is a registration form and the user enters all his information.  Then accidentally clicks on a link to navigate from it.

I found this on the web where it checks if a page is dirty if a person makes changes to any of the form input values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isDirty = false;
var msg = 'You haven\'t saved your changes.';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').change(function(){
        if(!isDirty){
            isDirty = true;
        }
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if(isDirty){
            return msg;
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

So this works great.  But how do I exclude some links that are pop-ups? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why would a popup call window.onbeforeunload? I don't think window.open will trigger an unload. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/7d5ZW/3/

Comment: Oh I did not realized that. You are right.  Thanks. Interesting my solution worked all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add onclick event listener on these inputs and "return false;"
Something like

```
$('a.className="popup"').onclick = function(){return false};
```

or

<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Text</a>