# How submit only data changed in html with or without javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

I have a form (HTML) with some inputs (checkbox) and I want to submit only inputs that user has clicked ou unclicked and ignore the others inputs.

I'm thinking in add a class (javascript) to the input when user change value. But I don't know if it is a good ideia.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Questions need to show some attempt at solving the problem. This one does not.

Comment: It may or may not be a good idea. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Diodeus based on the new close vote reasons, i think that requirement is more relaxed now.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673892/how-to-check-for-dirty-flag

Comment: @KevinB I tried. It's working but I'm feeling that's a workaround and not clever.

Comment: How do the inputs get initially populated? Are they returned from the server with a value? If that's the case, you can simply compare the value attribute to the value. .attr("value") vs .val(). the attribute will contain the value returned by the server, and the val will contain the current value. If the two are the same, then you know that input doesn't need to be sent.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but at time of submit they may have changed by other user. Usually users work in different rows and data change from 0 to 1. So saving only data user changed minimize the chance that one user undo another user sending back to 0.

Comment: @Diodeus thanks. I corrected to javascript.

Comment: @PedroLuizFaillaJunior that's a different problem entirely. My suggestion is no different from the class solution other than the fact that it doesn't use classes, and can recognize when someone changes a value, then decides to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the form that submits onClick() and calls a Javascript. When that happens you then search what values have been unchecked and then use the Javascript to submit it to the next page to handle the response.

However not sure what you are trying to achieve doing this...

Comment: Like Google to mark a important email? I liked it. Will try this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Class approach is working.

When user click on input I add class "envia":

```
$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("envia");
});
```

On submit I send only data with the class I want:

```
$.post("/financeiro/funcional/contasapagar.php", $(".envia").serialize(), function(data){
    //code here
});
```

Only data the user changed is send to server.